# Sending information to a view I'm returning to in Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have an app that includes a UIView in two different views. I want these two UIViews to show the same custom drawings, and have one be editable and one not be editable. When I segue from one view controller to the next (from the vc with the non-editable view to the editable one), I see the back button in UINavigation controller. Now, after I edit the view, I want the changes to be reflected in the non-editable view. I want to do this by being notified when the back button is pressed. So far, what I've tried hasn't worked:

```
public class BlockingViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    func navigationController(navigationController: UINavigationController, viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        print("In function")
    }
}
```

I took the navigationController method signature from https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/reference/UINavigationControllerDelegate_Protocol/index.html but I'm not sure what changes I made that made it not work. I took out the optional declaration because including it gave me an error message stating "optional can only be applied to protocol members." I thought this was a protocol member, but I guess not.

Answer (score 0):

That function declaration is incorrect. It should look like this,

```
func navigationController(navigationController: UINavigationController, didShowViewController viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        println("In function")
    }
```

(or willShowViewController, if that's the one you want)

Comment: Why is that required in this case, rather than being the method name or something? It seems pointless to call the function "navigationController" when it could be called "willShowViewController". Also, why is it allowable to put that before the parameter name?

Comment: Changing to that gave me an error, then changing it to
public func navigationController(navigationController: UINavigationController, willShowViewController viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool)

didn't give me an error, but it also didn't get called when I pressed the back button.

Comment: @user1493950, as to your first comment, Apple named it that way, so that's the way it is -- I just typed in "navigationContr", and then picked that method from the completion list it put up. Have you set the controller where you have this code to be the delegate of the navigation controller?

Comment: Can I set the delegate from the storyboard? I'm not sure how to do this, or what a delegate is for exactly.

Comment: I think I could do it in code when I segue, but I'm not segueing from the UINavigationController, rather from a UIViewController to another UIViewController, so I'm not sure where UINavigationController reference would come from.

Comment: @user1493950, no, you can't set it in the storyboard. Just add this line, self.navigationController?.delegate = self to the viewDidLoad method of your controller. If you don't know what a delegate is, then you should do some reading, because they're very important in iOS programming. I would start with Apple's documentation.